# jquery validation engine always getting same response on ajax validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, jquery-validation-engine

I have jquery validate engine validating a form. For example the code to check mobileno is already exists in database :

```
MobileNumber/Login Id : 
<input type="text"  class="k-textbox validate[required,custom[phone],ajax[ajaxMobileCallCfm]]  text-input" value="" name="mobileno"  id="mobileno"/>
```

and call validate engine

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
            jQuery("#register").validationEngine();

});
```

inline validation rules in the language file(jquery.validationEngine-en)

```
"ajaxMobileCallCfm": {
                    "url": "checkmobileno.cfm",
                    "alertTextOk": "* This username is available",
                    "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
                    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                }
```

and checkmobileno.cfm

```
<cfset mobileno=#mobileno#>
<cfset arrayToJs = ArrayNew(2)>
  <cfif #mobileno# eq "8888888888">
    <cfset arrayToJs[1][1]="mobileno">
    <cfset arrayToJs[1][2]=true>
    <cfset arrayToJs[1][3]='This user is available'>
 <cfelse>
        <cfset arrayToJs[1][1]="mobileno">
        <cfset arrayToJs[1][2]=false>
        <cfset arrayToJs[1][3]='This user is already taken'>
  </cfif>

 <cfset theJSON = #SerializeJSON(arrayToJs)#>

<cfoutput> 
 #theJSON#
</cfoutput>
```

Now,checking if a mobile is available on the blur or keyup event.

when i try with number,it always show *** This user is already taken**.please help me where the problem.

Thanks

Comment: If that code is accurate, then any number other than "8888888888" would return "This user is already taken"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simon said,

```
<cfif mobileno eq "8888888888">
    <cfset arrayToJs[1][1]="mobileno">
    <cfset arrayToJs[1][2]=true>
    <cfset arrayToJs[1][3]='This user is available'>
<cfelse>
```

means that the only number available is 8888888888

I think what you meant to say is 
`<cfif mobileno neq "8888888888">` or whatever list of numbers is not already taken. I assume the end product would check a database and look more like `<cfif not qUsedNumbers.recordCount>`

also...

```
<cfset mobileno=#mobileno#> <!--- is redundant--->

<!--- and you don't need so many pound signs. --->
<cfset mobileno=#mobileno#> 
<!--- should be --->
<cfset mobileno=mobileno> 

<cfif #mobileno# eq "8888888888"> 
<!--- should be --->
<cfif mobileno eq "8888888888">

<cfset theJSON = #SerializeJSON(arrayToJs)#> 
<!--- should be --->
<cfset theJSON = SerializeJSON(arrayToJs)>
```